# Равенство False и 0 в Python

Tags: python

Почему в `Python` `False==0` дает `True` и почему не используется `is` в функции `set` ? То есть, вот такая строчка:

```
print set([False, 0])
```

позволяет вывести:

```
set([False])
```

Куда делся 0 ? Все из-за `==` ?

Кстати, такая вот строчка `print set([1, True])` дает результат `set([1])`. Почему на этот раз пропал `True`, а 1 остался ?

Неужtли True и False просто макросы для 0 и 1 ? Но почему тогда  `True is 1` дает `False` ?

Comment: True + 1 == 2. По факту да, алиасы. Но типы таки разные

Comment: То есть, если посмотреть исходники интерпретатора, то можно найти что-то типа `#define True 1` ?

Comment: даже открывать не надо, смотрите ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю станет понятнее, если вывести родительские классы `bool`:

```
>>> True.__class__.__bases__
(<type 'int'>,)
```

То есть по факту да, True и False - это числа. Соответственно 1 и 0.

Comment: То есть, bool - это небольшая надстройка на int ?

Comment: такое практически во всех языках программирования. Ну кроме java, там есть Boolean, но это для эстетов

Comment: @faoxis именно https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d264235f6e066611b412f7c2e1603866e0f7f1b/Include/boolobject.h#L22

Comment: @faoxis `bool` тип это просто потомок `int` типа. Вы можете свой потомок создать: `class MyIntSubclass(int):pass`. В сторону: [`set` использует hash, а не равенство](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c4c67bf253ee68ffbb94227538df9eb)

Comment: @FeroxTL не понял, что демонтрируется строка `#define Py_True ((PyObject *) &_Py_TrueStruct)` по ваше ссылке. Из нее ясно, что Py_True - некая структура и все. Или я чего-то не уловил ?

Comment: @KoVadim не согласен. Во многих языках (например, С++) false - 0, a True не false (!false).

Comment: @faoxis ради интереса гляньте на _Py_TrueStruct  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d264235f6e066611b412f7c2e1603866e0f7f1b/Objects/boolobject.c#L181 - объявляется то непосредственно тут

Comment: @faoxis это никак не противоречит моему комментарию.