# Python Почему в одном True в другом False

Tags: python

почему если в код ввести:

```
print(1 == 1 != False)
```

вывод: `True`

а если ввести:

```
print(2 == 1 != False)
```

то вывод: `False`

Answer (score 5):

Объяснения, которые даны в других ответах, вообще-то неправильные. И проверить это довольно легко, вот пример:

```
print(False == False == False)
print(0 == 0 == 0)
```

Согласно объяснениям из других ответов тут должно получиться:

```
(False == False) == False -> True == False -> False
(0 == 0) == 0 -> True == 0 -> False
```

Однако же питоном выводится обратный результат:

```
True
True
```

Объяснение простое. Результат таких действий определяется по следующей схеме:

```
a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z -> a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z
                                     ^^^         ^^^
```

Т.е. выражение:

```
False == False == False
```

Вычисляется как:

```
(False == False) and (False == False)
```

Объясняется это в эпическом тексте [WTF Python!](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython), который, похоже, многие ещё до сих пор не прочитали.

Примеры автора вопроса, соответственно:

```
1 == 1 != False -> 1 == 1 and 1 != False -> True and True -> True
2 == 1 != False -> 2 == 1 and 1 != False -> False and True -> False
```

И, как правильно дополнил Roman Konoval, такая форма записи вообще была придумана в питоне, чтобы покороче записывать условия такого вида:

```
0 <= x <= 100 -> 0 <= x and x <= 100
a < b < c < d < e -> a < b and b < c and ...
```

Comment: Остается только добавить, что это нужно для того, чтоб сократить запись типа `2 < x and x < 5` до `2 < x < 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте поэтапно, действия выполняются слева направо:

1. `1==1 это True`, `True != False` это правда, соответственно вывод будет True
2. `2==1 это False`, `False != False` это ложь, потому что они равны. Соответственно вывод будет False

Comment: Попробуйте проверить, чему равно выражение `0 == 0 != False`, например )

Comment: Ну то есть для примеров из вопроса ваше объяснение сработало, но это просто так удачно совпало.

Answer (score -1):

Есть ещё более простое объяснение. В Python тип `bool` - это потомок типа `int`, т.е. True и False - это 1 и 0 соответственно. Таким образом, получаем:

в первом примере:

```
1 != 0
```

Результат: `True`

во втором примере:

```
0 != 0
```

Результат: `False`

См.также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553527/208075

Comment: Проверьте, какой результат даёт выражение `0 == 0 == True` и попробуйте объяснить его. Про соответствие `int` и `bool` вы правы, но тут дело не в этом.